# Google insight question

Tags: seo, google, research

I am checking the word mobile on google insight.

http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=mobile&cmpt=q

I see a bar with mobile ]]]]]]]]]]]]] 62

Then on google help page -

I get this. However, I am unable to understand.

**The numbers on the graph reflect how many searches have been done for a particular term, relative to the total number of searches done on Google over time. They don't represent absolute search volume numbers, because the data is normalized and presented on a scale from 0-100.**

**My question is what does the number 62 determine? Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2):

100 = Most active searches

0 = Least active searches

That means that "mobile" (64) is above average (50) in terms of search popularity. But not by a whole lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "But not by a whole lot". I didn't got you. can you please give me few examples. I have been trying to understand.

Comment: The numbers are scaled down from the real search volume. So if the most popular search term was searched for a million times, mobile would have been searched 620,000 times to get that number 62. Alternatively, the number of searches for "mobile" is 62% of whatever is the most popular search term. I would say that 62 is still very popular.

Comment: I also want to know, how to determine whether such number 64 (mobile) keyord is good for me or not. How can I make optimum utilization of this information?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - a much better explanation then mine